# How to get list of available applications "Open with..." Linux/Windows

Tags: linux, windows, qt

How to get list of available applications "Open with..." Linux/Windows?
Icon, display name, path to executable.
Is this function exsists in Qt?
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this could help [StandardLocation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#StandardLocation-enum) - `QStandardPaths::ApplicationsLocation`

Answer (score 0):

No. There is only [QDesktopServices::openUrl()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl), which opens a file or link in the default application assigned to it.